# InvocationTargetException after using ProGuard

Tags: java, ant, obfuscation, proguard, executable-jar

I obfuscate my jar with ProGuard using Eclipse Ant script.

I use configuration file almost identical from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7511926/1360074). I have just added more references to proper libraries using `-libraryjars` option and omit two warnings using `-dontnote`

After that I include generated jar into fat jar with those libraries. It works okay if above mentioned .cfg is used.

But not much obfuscation is done. In [examples for typical application](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html) it is said to use

```
-keep public class mypackage.MyMain {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

So this is changed

```
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```

After regenerating new fat jar it throws Exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at mypackage.a.d.a.a(SourceFile:11)
        at mypackage.a.d.a.a(SourceFile:44)
        at mypackage.MyMain.main(SourceFile:61)
        ... 5 more
```

How can I fix it? Please, give me some advice how to investigate more on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this specific problem with inspecting the obfuscated jar with JD Java Decompiler.

In there way a line:

```
String path = JarEclipse.class.getResource("MyClass.class").toString();
```

which caused `NullPointerException` because `getResource` returns null, because `MyClass.class` was renamed.